# The response contained an InResponseTo attribute [] but no saved authentication request was found - Springboot integrated with SAML2 Okta

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta

I follow this guide exactly, i can login- logout properly in normal scenario
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/08/05/spring-boot-saml

The issue happens in this screnario

- Open 2 browser tabs at same time(Tab1,Tab2): -> access to https://localhost
  -> it will automatically redirect to this screen below:
  [image]
- Tab2 : Click Sign In -> Can login successfully!
  [image]
- Tab1: Click Sign In -> Error beelow:
  [image]

**Please Help me if you face this issue alss, i am not sure how to fix this**

Comment: i have no ideas how to fix it, anyone faced this issue before?